# clicking a link and finding the closest element down

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have a link that, when clicked, will find and put some text in the closest div down. Here's my code so far which sadly doesn't work:

```js
$('.products').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var pID = $(this).attr('data-pID');
  $(this).find('.categories').html(pID);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul style="margin-left:5px; margin-top:10px;">

  <li>
    <a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;" class="products" data-pid="1">Product A</a>
    <div class="categories"></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;" class="products" data-pid="2">Product B</a>
    <div class="categories"></div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: For reference: [Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), and [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) vs [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

Comment: @Damien: Wouldn't you also need closest up? like `prev()` or `siblings()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find` looks at the child elements. Your `div` isn't a child, it's a sibling, so use `.next`

```
$(this).next('.categories').html(pID);
```

Comment: Doh! I didn't see that and or know that. Thanks for the input!